# Is there a way to fix the Bootstrap container width while changing the browser window size?

Tags: html, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I am writing a website, and am using the grid system of the Twitter's bootstrap. I have been searching for a way to fix the size of the website's width, but have not been successful. The think is that I want to completely fix the size (not allowing the web to shrink at all) while user change the size of the window or while they are using devices that has smaller screen such as iPhone. More specifically, I'd rather want the browser to display a fraction of my website instead of resizing the page, which actually disrupt all of the text formatting. Below is how I set the css of the website. I thought defining the min-width would do the trick, but it's still not working...

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container{
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 960px;
    width: auto !important;
    width: 960;
    }
}

.container {
    padding-left: auto;
    padding-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}
```

I just read the documentation, and found that bootstrap is actually for responsive web design. I wonder if it's possible to fix the layout of the website using the bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<div id="main-container" class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>what ever you want</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
#main-container{
  width: 1000px !important
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:hidden;
  height:100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks sonill, it works now. Turned out to be my mistake. I had the nab-bar set up as justified, so the menu section of the website is still responsive to window sizing, but now every elements of the website is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, totally possible to fix the width of a Bootstrap build. Check out the documentation here for step-by-step directions: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

Though I'd strongly recommend against this, if you want to prevent your page from scaling (as opposed to actively reformatting itself via media queries), you'll want to manipulate the meta viewport tag.

Remove the media queries per Bootstrap's docs, and add this in:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

That should prevent any scaling, but it will also make for a disorienting experience. More info on the viewport tag here: http://blog.javierusobiaga.com/stop-using-the-viewport-tag-until-you-know-ho

Answer (score 0):

Its preety easy

Just add id to the main container and name it "main-container"

And add this in your styles.css

## main-container{

```
width: 1000px !important;
margin : 0 auto;
```

}

Comment: Hi Sonill, This works for some divs of the website, but there are also some text in divs that I defined their class as col-md-xx that still changes their content while scaling the browser window.